MySQL POINT and POLY not Representing GEO data
I need to store POINT and POLY fields that represent points and areas on an Image Map, not GEO lat/lng coordinates.
Because I'm not representing Geography does not make sense to use the ST_PointFromText() and ST_PolygonFromText() functions which use WKT strings.
How do I store arbitrary points and polygons?
The following code fails:
INSERT INTO geofences (space_id, position, poly)
VALUES(
    12,
    POINT(18 -63),
    POLYGON(579 157, 715 338, 485 341, 579 157)
);

If I wrap in these function this also fails:
INSERT INTO geofences (space_id, position, poly)
VALUES(
    12,
    ST_PointFromText('POINT(590 300)'),
    ST_PolygonFromText('POLYGON(579 157, 715 338, 485 341, 579 157)')
);

ERROR 3037 (22023): Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromtext.


I think you still have to use those functions to parse these values, POINT() and POLYGON() are not functions.

I had tried to use the functions to parse these values (added sample statement above) but get the error: ERROR 3037 (22023): Invalid GIS data provided to function st_polygonfromtext.

You probably need to pass 0 as srid. That is unitless cartesian pane
